# How to make ripple like effect with your audio like in google meet?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, webrtc

[How to make ripple like effect with your audio like in google meet?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejh6d.png)

As you see in my avatar there is a grey circle present which is generated using my audio.